# How do I get my Bitcoin "Spendable" instead of it being "Non-Spendable" on my Blockchain Account?

Tags: blockchain

I have been fighting this all night and day and haven't made any progress. I used a CoinFlip ATM to buy BitCoin or deposit USD into the machine. I have an account at Blockchain and I used the right QR code to deposit, or buy, the Bitcoin. My transaction is showing in my Blockchain Account but it's showing as non-spendable. I need to make a payment on something and need to know ASAP how to make it spendable to transfer. Something to do with a Private Key, that I have no idea how to get either. HELP Please!

Comment: How did you add this unspendable address to your wallet? To spend funds, you need the private key, and you either know that, or not. You can't deduce a private key from a public key/address. If the address is 'unspendable', then it is likely just a 'watch-only' address, meaning your wallet software doesn't have the private key for it.

Comment: I don't recall getting a private key. When would that have happened? I had to transfer the transaction into the Blockchain account by copy and pasting the wallet ID (I think that's what it was). I did get a receipt for the transaction when I deposited the cash into the CoinFlip ATM. Would the key be there?

Comment: I guess where would I find the private key or when would I have received it??

Comment: Generally, your wallet software will create the private key, and then derive the public key and address from the private key. Based on this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aL_OPx1MSc) it looks like the CoinFlip ATM pays to an address you provide. So where did that address originate from?

Comment: If you want to post the txID it may be helpful to figure out what is going on, but doing so will hurt your privacy. It may also be possible that your transaction just isn't confirmed yet, and the wallet software is not letting you spend it until it is confirmed.

Comment: No, it shows confirmed and everything and my wallet software is the Blockchain account, right? Because that is all I have and when I deposited on the CoinFlip machine I got an address from Blockchain mobile when I first opened the app on my phone it generates a QR code that I scanned. Is there another program I need for the wallet? Is it called Electrum or something? Because a friend told me that just now.

Comment: And I'd be happy to show you anything on here too because if I can't figure it out I lose my money anyway or if you can figure it out and take it,well then its gone too, so really I only have a 33% chance of getting my money. So, alright what do you need me to show you? The TX ID??

Comment: Just so you know: NEVER share your private key, mnemonic seed phrase, or wallet log-in information with someone else online. Having that data could allow someone to steal your coins. Anyone legit offering to help will never ask for those things. However, sharing your txID, public address, or public key is safe from theft, but hurts your privacy (people will know which tx is yours).

Comment: Oh that's fine I don't mind it that much I suppose. But thank you for the advice to stay away from people asking for those things I'll definitely keep that in mind......

The TX ID is: RPMDS3

anything else you think you need to help??

Comment: I downloaded the software called Electrum and created a wallet and all with that ONLY transaction and address in there but it needs a SEED which I have and know but it isn't letting me click on the button to enter that info

Comment: When you first started the blockchain wallet, did you do anything like 'import address' in the app? The first receiving address the wallet shows you should be spendable, I would recommend contacting blockchain's customer service team. You shouldn't need to use Electrum to spend the funds. Either the blockchain wallet has the private key and you can spend from there, or it doesn't because you imported the address from somewhere (and if you don't have the key otherwise (ie, you used some other software to make the key), the funds will be unspendable).

Comment: Yes I had to import the address and entered the address not the private key because I never knew the private key. What I think I need to do is make the key like you said but I'm not quite sure I know how to do that. Is it through the Electrum wallet? Blockchain? Don't know

Comment: No, it is impossible to find the private key for a given address. No software can do it, you either have the key, or you don't. Where did you find the address that you imported? It must have come from somewhere. Where?

Comment: It came from a URL that one of the support guys at Blockchain.com gave me. It's this right here: 
: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/17ui5GVdwtfa8AjwxnpWyEpDHWmxbXR88o)

Then they're telling me that I need a private key but I don't remember even seeing one

Comment: Well, I feel like a jackass!! I have been using my laptop to try all this and I just opened up my phone and the Blockchain app and apparently the Private Key was stored on the phone app and so it released the funds. Thank you for trying and all your help it is appreciated!!

Comment: no worries, I’m glad you recovered the funds

Comment: Good to see the issue is resolved. Can you either answer your own question, or close it?

Answer (score 1):

OP answered own question:

> I have been using my laptop to try all this and I just opened up my phone and the Blockchain app and apparently the Private Key was stored on the phone app and so it released the funds.